# Setting Transparency of Polygon in R

Tags: r, polygon

I have a plot that contains multiple overlapping polygons and I would like to set the transparency of them. However, I failed to do so by using either `col=rgb(0, 1, 0,0.5)` or `col=adjustcolor("dark green",alpha.f=0.5)`.

Here is the original code:

```
  x_val <- seq(0, 8, length = 1000)
  y_val <- dnorm(x_val, mean=4)
  plot(x_val, y_val, type = "l", axes = TRUE, frame = TRUE, lwd = 3, xlab = "x", ylab = "Density")
  mu1=6.2
  curve(dnorm(x,mu1),add=TRUE,lwd=2)
  x4 <- seq(qnorm(.25), 8, length.out=100)
  polygon(c(x4+mu1, rev(x4)+mu1),c(dnorm(x4), rep(0, length(x4))), col=rgb(0, 1, 0,0.5))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This worked fine for me --- the green polygon was semi-transparent and I could see the black line underneath. Incidentally, you are only drawing *one* polygon, with many sides, not multiple polygons...

Comment: @JDL Sorry for the confusion, this is just the part of one polygon, I left out the code for other polygons. When I ran this chunk of code in RStudio, the polygon is filled with white instead of green. After seeing your comment, I tried to knit it into pdf and the green color shows up. Thank you!

Comment: hmm, it may be device or version-dependent behaviour. Mine worked in Rstudio. If you post the results of `.Platform` and your Rstudio version number maybe someone else can help, but it's probably just a Rstudio bug on your particular version/platform that you may not be able to do much about (other than upgrade)